# Understand Domain and subdomain Website

Tags: subdomain

I know domain and subdomain like

```
domain: mywebsite.com
subdomain: sub.mywebsite.com
```

But what about?

```
mywebsite.com.vn
```

Is that subdomain? anyone can refer good link to read thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
mywebsite.com.vn
```

is also kind of subdomain.  Actually Domain have a domain registry which is kind of tree structure that goes several level deep; here **com.vn** is third level domain names are standard and branch off of the second-level domains. Wikipedia have good explanation of this,  for example,

```
.ac.uk - academic (tertiary education, further education colleges and research           establishments) and learned societies
.co.uk - general use (usually commercial)
.gov.uk - government (central and local)
```

All above sub-domains are bifurcation of main domain which tries to explain specialized mention of main domain.